# How to increment an array value

Tags: javascript, ejs

This is the code I have - this turns the first array element but I need to increment through each array element rather.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">     
        <% _.each(answer_options, function(a, adx){ %>
        <label>
            <% if(question_type == '') { %>
            <input type="checkbox" name="form-field-checkbox" class="ace-checkbox-2"><span
                class="lbl"> <%= answer_options._answer %><%= answer_options[0].a_option %></span>
            <% } else { %>
            <input type="radio" name="form-field-radio"><span class="lbl"><%= answer_options[0].a_option %>&nbsp;<%= answer_options[0].answer %></span>
            <% } %>
        </label>
        <% }) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no this is not javascript

Comment: please flag the template language

Comment: is this [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

The each function iterates through each value in answer options, but you're always selecting the first value from the array by doing `answer_options[0].a_option` instead of doing `a.a_option`. The `each` function gives `a` and `adx` where `a` is the value and `adx` is the index where that value lives.

```
<% _.each(answer_options, function(a, adx){ %>
   <label>
       <% if(question_type == '') { %>
          <input type="checkbox" name="form-field-checkbox" class="ace-checkbox-2"><span
                class="lbl"> <%= a._answer %><%= a.a_option %></span>
            <% } else { %>
          <input type="radio" name="form-field-radio"><span class="lbl"><%= a.a_option %>&nbsp;<%= a.answer %></span>
       <% } %>
    </label>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: @user2904967 mark this as the answer if it answers your question.